# Generate hierarchy from a many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, tree, nested, hierarchy

I'm having trouble to generate the hierarchy from the data consumed from an API.

At this moment, there's a many-to-many relationships between two models: `Tag`s and `Node`s.

Now, what I need is set a `parent_id` on the `Tag` model to know which `Tag` is its parent. This will be recursive because there are several levels of depth.

The thing is that this process needs to be elaborated from the actual data of the many to many relationships. So I've been playing with the collections (`Node::all()`/`Tag::all()`) to try to create this structure, to then mass-assign the ids of the parent Tag in the children tags.

My idea is to load the tags from the `Node`s, then create a new item in the collection for every tag child of the node

so this:

```
|
|__Node A
|  |__Tag 1
|  |__Tag 2
|  |__Tag 3
|
|__Node B
|  |__Tag 1
|  |__Tag 3
|  
|__Node c
   |__Tag 1
   |__Tag 2
```

Could be converted to this (i know that every item needs to have a unique key, I was thinking assigning one temporary):

```
|
|__Node A
|  |__Tag 1
|
|__Node A
|  |__Tag 2
|
|__Node A
|  |__Tag 3
|
|__Node B
|  |__Tag 1
|
|__Node B
|  |__Tag 3
|  
|__Node c
|  |__Tag 1
|  
|__Node c
   |__Tag 2
```

Then I could groupBy (recursively) the tag key resuting into this:

```
|__Tag 1
   |
   |__Tag 2
   |  |
   |  |__Node A
   |  |__Node C
   |
   |__Tag 3
      |
      |__Node A
      |__Node B
```

My problem is that, don't know (yet) how to make this transformation properly.

Comment: For me the Tag model should have a one to many relationship with himself, i.e. childs.

Comment: @dparoli of course, that's the next step, the thing is, in order to know which is its parent, I'm trying to save in its `parent_id` the id of the inmeadiate parent.. then defining that relationship I could get the desired structure.

Comment: You get nodes with tags from an API and want to store them in your database?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I fetch the data from a service whenever there is a new client in our company. The thing is that this structure needs to be generated every time this happens (to add the tags/nodes from this new client).

Comment: Have you already written any code? In your example, why is `Tag 1` the parent of `Tag 2` and `Tag 3`?

Comment: @jonasStaudenmeir because is present in every node, then the nodes are grouped by the common tag, generating the subgroups Tag2/tag3

Comment: You should consider using the principle of Hoffman code - I would take the most common Tag and put him as root - then keep drill down while as each layer (same depth node) has same number of occurrences. The Node will be treated as leaf - insert each as a leaf after insert all its Node to the tree. Notice forest case when Node has new Tag

Comment: @dWinder that was (still is) my initial idea. But don't really know a good way to do this. Could you share a sample of how can I accomplish it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How should the result look like, if you add "Tag 4" to "Node 1"? What will be the parent of "Tag 4"? Since "Tag 4" is only related to "Node A", it could be child of "Tag 1", "Tag 2" or "Tag 3", because each of them "contain" a superset of "Node A".

Comment: Here is one [sql "brute force" method](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tmKiE1imUdZPaddUam7X33/0). Uncomment the last insert line, to see the problem I meant above.

Comment: @HCK Did my post help you? Was it understood-able?

Answer (score 1):

**Use a best practice**

First of all I suggest you to have a look at [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/) toturial. as a best practice to make hierarchy data by using weights.

**Use Eloquent**

and also as you use Laravel eloquent relations as it's active record

```
//in Tag Model
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tag', 'parent_id');   
}

public function parent(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tag', 'parent_id');
}

public function nodes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Node', 'node_id', 'node_id');   
}
```

then you can get the result

```
//there should be a relation for node also 
Tag::with('parent', 'children.children', 'node')->get();
```

**a simple php way**

but also Here is a simple way I think:

```
foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {
    $tagTree[$value['tag_id']] = $value;
    $tagTree[$value['tag_id']]['child'] = array();
}

foreach ($tagTree as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['parent_id'] == 0) {
        $root[$key] = &$tagTree[$key];
    } else {
        $tagTree[$value['parent_id']]['child'][$key] = &$tagTree[$key];
    }

    //here you can check if is there any node for current tag insert 
    //$tagTree[$value['parent_id']]['node'][] = ...
}
```

Comment: What you put here is true and its a good way to store this data. The thing is, my problem isn't the way to store the tree but the way to define which `Tag` is the parent of a subgroup of `Tag`s. I mean, how to define the `parent_id` attribute of each `Tag`. Then defining the self-relationships (as you stated in the **Use Eloquent** section for example) I could easily shape the tree.

Comment: What do you mean, find parent IDs according to existing data? If yes, I see you consider a tag related to all nodes as the root, is it right?

Comment: That's it. Then, go and find the next big group below to relate them to the next child/parent and so on.

Comment: The nodes are related to every member of the tree (of tags). I mean, the service is structured that way the problem is that the data doesn't make it easy to fetch the right structure through an endpoint.

Comment: I couldn't find a rule to get just children of a tag but by using the middle table (as its many to many) for each tag you can get all related tags (step 2 in your question) if you can group by then. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/meFX3CuEs8MDKfxo7PeKY2/1

Comment: if you remove node B then tag 2 is parent of tag 1 or tag 1 is parent of tag 2 or both are root nodes? and what about tag 3 then, just because both tag 1 and tag 3 would have a same node A in that case would cause tag 1 become tag 3's parent?